# Using VBA to call a stored procedure in SQL Server, passing one parameter. I'm getting an error, multiple-step OLD DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Going round in circles on this. I'm using VBA to call a stored procedure to pull in some data from SQL Server.

It passes one parameter which is valuation date. I have tested this SQL Server stored procedure and it works fine in sql with all dates. Now the strange thing is the query works perfectly fine from VBA and SQL for dates 10/31/2019 and previous, but for 11/30/2019 and 12/31/2019, I get an error

> Run-time error '-20147217887 (8004e21)': Multiple-step OLe DB operation generated errors.

I can't figure out why it would work for the some dates but not others when it works for all date directly in SQL. Thanks in advance.

Here is the VBA code:

```vb
 Sub GroupExperience()

     'SQL code
     Dim ValDate As Date

     ValDate = Format(Range("ValDate"), "mm-dd-yyyy")

     Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
     Dim cnSQL As ADODB.Connection
     Dim sqlcommand As ADODB.Command, prm As Object

     Set cnSQL = New ADODB.Connection
     cnSQL.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=bddc1didw1;Initial Catalog=Actuarial; Trusted_connection=Yes; Integrated Security='SSPI'"

     Set sqlcommand = New ADODB.Command
     sqlcommand.ActiveConnection = cnSQL

     'GroupExperience

     sqlcommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
     sqlcommand.CommandText = "[HRT\akapur].[AllGroupExperience]"
     Set prm = sqlcommand.CreateParameter("ValDate", adDate, adParamInput)

     sqlcommand.Parameters.Append prm
     sqlcommand.Parameters("ValDate").Value = ValDate
     Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
     rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
     rs.Open sqlcommand

     Sheets("Experience Data").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

       Dim pt As PivotTable
       Set pt = Sheets("Experience").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

       pt.RefreshTable

 End Sub
```

Comment: When it fails maybe check the connection's Errors collection and see if there's anything useful there

Comment: the collection errors in VBA? Everything looks normal.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb